# ExpressJs Routing: Could not find official documentation for '_startTime' property in request object

Tags: express, routes

I need to check the time at which request is send to the server. For this I explored the 'req' object. It has a property of '_startTime' which gives me the System time of the Client machine from which request was sent.

I am not able to find the official documentation for this property.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, `_startTime` is not something that Express sets on the request object.

The logger module `morgan` adds it, but it's convention that properties whose name starts with an underscore are "private": they are for internal use only, and should not be relied upon.

However, it's not very difficult to add such a property yourself. In Express, the most logical method would be to use a middleware function for that:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req._requestStarted = new Date();
  next();
});
```

Because it's your own application code that sets this property, you can always rely on it existing (as opposed to `_startTime` which, because it's for internal use by `morgan`, may be removed or renamed in the future).

To nitpick: this value does not reflect the system time of the client from which the request was sent, it's the time on the server at which the server received the request. In HTTP, clients generally don't send their own local time along with a request.